# xcode 4.5.2 Can't make tabbared application

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have xcode 4.5.2. I've tried for a whole day but i couldn't manage to find an appropriate tutorial or sample to create a tab bar application
If i create a tabbed application, i don't know how to add tabs into controller.
If i create an empty application, i can not start it with tab bar controller on window.
I created a xib file. Make it the main source interface source in targets. Add a window and a tabbarcontroller there and link them with the outlets of the appDelegate.
In appDelegate.m in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions i add the following code

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.window addSubview:self.tabbarController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and nothing helps.
What's the matter?
How can I do that?

Comment: search...read...try...ask :)

Comment: My problem was i was ought to search the keyword storyboard as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this tutorial may help you ,
[Creating a Tab Bar Application Using Storyboards](http://fuelyourcoding.com/creating-a-tab-bar-application-using-storyboards-in-xcode-4-2/).